# Why im getting an error on IEnumerator?

Tags: c#

```
public void CheckFileType(string directoryPath)
        {
            IEnumerator files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).GetEnumerator();
        }
```

The error: Error    1   Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: Not exactly answering your question, but is there a reason you're calling `GetEnumerator` and not simply iterating on it using `foreach` or LINQ? EDIT: From the full source code you posted for a moment that I glanced at (and now you've rolled back), I didn't immediately see any reason for _manually_ iterating on the `GetFiles` result. Simply use a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare what type you're enumerating over:

```
IEnumerator<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).GetEnumerator();
```

If you're unsure of the type use `var`:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).GetEnumerator();
```

then the compiler will do all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerator<T>` is generic and requires a type, for example:

```
IEnumerator<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: But there *is* a non-generic `IEnumerator`, so you don't need to provide a generic type.

Comment: I don't think this would compile - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1):

The type you are referring to is generic, which means you need to supply a generic argument, like so:

```
IEnumerator<string> files = [...];
```

It so happens that there is a non-generic version of `IEnumerator`, but it's in the `System.Collections` namespace, not the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.  If you want to use the non-generic version (which you really shouldn't; you should use the generic version) you'll need to add a `using` for that namespace or use the fully qualified name.